# Loading an ontology from string in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, ontology, owlready

We have a Pyspark pair RDD which stores the path of `.owl` files as key and the file contents as value.

I wish to carry out reasoning using Owlready2. To load an ontology from OWL files, the `get_ontology()` function is used. However, the given function expects an IRI (a sort of URL) to the file, whereas I have the file contents as a `str` in Python.

Is there a way I could make this work out?

I have tried the following:

- Used `get_ontology(file_contents).load()` --> this obviously does not work as the function expects a file path.
- Used `get_ontology(file_contents)` --> no error, but the ontology does not get loaded, so reasoning does not happen.

Comment: save it locally and use `get_ontology`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The `load()` function in Owlready2 has a couple of more arguments which are not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. The function definitions of the package can be seen [here](https://github.com/pwin/owlready2/blob/master/namespace.py).

Quoting from there, `def load(self, only_local = False, fileobj = None, reload = False, reload_if_newer = False, **args)` is the function signature.

We can see that a `fileobj` can also be passed, which is `None` by default. Further, the line `fileobj = open(f, "rb")` tells us that the file needs to be read in binary mode.

Taking all this into consideration, the following code worked for our situation:

```
from io import BytesIO # to create a file-like object
my_str = RDDList[1][1] # the pair RDD cell with the string data
my_str_as_bytes = str.encode(my_str) # convert to binary
fobj = BytesIO(my_str_as_bytes) 

abox = get_ontology("some-random-path").load(fileobj=fobj) # the path is insignificant, notice the 'fileobj = fobj'.
```